# Spark 2.4 & Scala - Replace the Columns with implicit Function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Dataset which is read from SQL Server with 10 Columns and 1 Column has data

```
Hierarchy
/234324/12121
/234324/12122
/234324/12123
/234324/12124
```

Now I have written an implicit Function to split the same

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.split

    implicit def splitFlexType(typepath: String): String = split(typepath,"\\\\").last
```

Now I want to apply the function on the column and replace the values in the same column (Not a new Column, same one - Hierarchy)

```
myDF.withColumn("hierarchy", splitFlexType(myDF("hierarchy_flex")))
```

Error on IDE

[image]

throws error! Any Pointers would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- `split` (from `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`) takes a `Column`, not a `String`.
- `split` retunrns a `Column`, which has no method `last`
- no need to use `implicit` here

so you can use:

```
val df = Seq(
  "/234324/12121"
).toDF("hierarchy")

def splitFlexType(typepath: Column): Column = reverse(split(typepath,"/"))(0)

df.withColumn("hierarchy",splitFlexType($"hierarchy"))
  .show()
```

gives :

```
+---------+
|hierarchy|
+---------+
|    12121|
+---------+
```

alternatively, you can do the same with an UDF:

```
val splitFlexType = udf((typepath: String) =>  typepath.split("/").last)
```

where the usage and the result is the same as above

Comment: Very nicely explained, thanks a lot, I was using org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.split instead of org.apache.spark.sql.functions.split, My Bad should have mentioned above